# Unable to set PDF margins to print from iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I am displaying the PDF in `UIWebView` from my app.

```
- (void) startPrinting
{
    UIPrintInfo *pi = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    pi.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    pi.jobName = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    pi.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
    pi.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    pic.printInfo = pi;
    pic.showsPageRange = NO;
    pic.printFormatter = self.webView.viewPrintFormatter;
    UIPrintPageRenderer *renderer = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
    self.webView.viewPrintFormatter.printPageRenderer.headerHeight = 30.0f; //webView is the IBOutlet connected
    self.webView.viewPrintFormatter.printPageRenderer.footerHeight = 30.0f;
    self.webView.viewPrintFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 30.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f);
    self.webView.viewPrintFormatter.startPage = 0;
    [renderer addPrintFormatter:self.webView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
    pic.printPageRenderer = renderer;

    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic2, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Completed status = %d and error status = %@", completed, error);
    }];
}
```

And in NSObject class, following code uses standard A4 sized paper.

```
- (void)drawPDF:(NSString*)fileName
{
    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, CGRectZero, nil);
    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

    //[self drawText:@"Hello World" inFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];

    [self drawLabels];
    [self drawLogo]; 

    // Close the PDF context and write out the contents.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```

I have loaded the nib of size 612 x 792 to create the pdf. But when I take the printout from the printer, I get the print as shown in the following image.

[image]

How to get PDF resized to desired margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue after I added

```
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 1122), nil);
```

instead of

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
```

in drawPdf method.

Also, I changed the xib size from 612 x 792 to 792 x 1122 from where I generate the pdf.